# Python lxml library includes None in empty tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

As has been suggested by mzjn I am changing the whole question and trying to simplify it.

I have this XML:

```
<Content Version="1.0" Name="Cont">
 <Element Ref="Text_4158" ElementType="ItISSomething" GroupName="Some_Content">
  <body>
    <p>Some content is here.</p>
  </body>
 </Element>
 <Element Ref="List_585" ElementType="ListElements" GroupName="Lists">
  <body>
    <p><span class="bold">A list of things</span>: Element1, element2, element3, element4 element5.</p>
  </body>
 </Element>
</Content>
```

I want to modify the content of the lists and replace "," for "<,>". And I have this code:

```
from lxml import etree as et
def replace_commas(file):
   parser = et.parse(str(file))
   root = parser.getroot()
   xpath_expr = "//Element[starts-with(@Ref,'List_') \
or @GroupName='Lists']/descendant::*"
   elements = root.xpath(xpath_expr)
   for element in elements:
       if element.text is not None or element.tail is not None:
          text = str(element.text)
          text = text.replace(',', '<,>')
          tail = str(element.tail)
          tail = tail.replace(',','<,>')
          element.text = text
          element.tail = tail
   tree = et.ElementTree(root)
   tree.write(file, pretty_print=True)
```

The expected output should be:

```
<Content Version="1.0" Name="Cont">
 <Element Ref="Text_4158" ElementType="ItISSomething" GroupName="Some_Content">
  <body>
    <p>Some content is here.</p>
  </body>
 </Element>
 <Element Ref="List_585" ElementType="ListElements" GroupName="Lists">
  <body>
    <p><span class="bold">A list of things</span>: Element1&lt;,&gt; element2&lt;,&gt; element3&lt;,&gt; element4 element5.</p>
  </body>
 </Element>
</Content>
```

However my result is:

```
<Content Version="1.0" Name="Cont">
 <Element Ref="Text_4158" ElementType="ItISSomething" GroupName="Some_Content">
  <body>
    <p>Some content is here.</p>
  </body>
 </Element>
 <Element Ref="List_585" ElementType="ListElements" GroupName="Lists">
  <body>
    <p>None<span class="bold">A list of things</span>: Element1&lt;,&gt; element2&lt;,&gt; element3&lt;,&gt; element4 element5.</p>
  </body>
 </Element>
</Content>
```

Getting a None between the tags "p" and "span" and there should be nothing. What is wrong?

I hope this update to the question helps to understand the query and find a solution.

**Update:** Corrected the colon in the def replace_commas(file): and the indentation of et.ElementTree(root).

Also, I have found where the suggested solution by mzjn is giving error. I have in my xml this element:

```
<Element Ref="List_222"ElementType="ListElements" GroupName="Lists">
  <body>
    <p><span class="bold">List: <span class="italic">Important elements</span></span>: El1 (prop1), el2 (prop2), el3 (prop3); with a special property.</p>
  </body>
</Element>
```

In this element I get the NoneType in the tail of Important elements as it gets as value None.

I am not seeing how to solve it.

Comment: can you add the desirable case?

Comment: I have added the desirable case, that would be with the empty elements without the None value and I have added some info about my small research of the cause. However i have not found any.

Comment: Please simplify the question and create a [mcve].

Comment: There is a colon missing at the end of `def replace_commas(file)`. And the indentation of the `tree = et.ElementTree(root)` line does not look right.

Comment: You are write with the error of the missing colon, and the generation of the tree inside the loop was causing problems. Now I am getting the problem that with your suggested solution the `element.tail.replace` gives me the NoneType error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `text` property of an element is empty (does not have a value), it returns the built-in constant `None`.

The `text` property of the second `<p>` element is empty. But you use `text = str(element.text)`, which makes the `text` variable equal to the string `'None'`. That is what you see in the output.

If you check `text` and `tail` separately for each element, it should work:

```
for element in elements:
    if element.text is not None:
        element.text = element.text.replace(',', '<,>')
    if element.tail is not None:
        element.tail = element.tail.replace(',', '<,>')
```

Comment: I got error in the element.tail as I get a NoneType object has no attribute replace.

Comment: The point of `if element.tail is not None:` is to guard against such errors. I cannot explain why you get that error. You need to provide more information.

Comment: It returns me an empty element: <body><p/></body> . It is very weird. I don't know where look more.

Comment: I am debugging the code, it looks like it is an specific element that it gets None. However I am not able to find why.

Answer (score 0):

After looking I have finally found the solution to the empty tail of . Instead of checking if an element was not empty, I have solved it checking if is None do nothing, it is continue.:

```
for element in elements:
   if element.text is None:
       continue
   else:
       element.text = element.text.replace(',','<,>')
   if element.tail is None:
       continue
   else:
       element.tail = element.tail.replace(',','<,>')
   tree = et.ElementTree(root)
   tree.write(args.file,  pretty_print=True)
```

With this fix around I have been able to fix the issue.